# how to get network connection type in android web view?

Tags: android, html, networking, webview

how can i get network connection type in android webview.

my dev environment
- android os ver: 4.1.2
- webview

my code here.

```
// check connection
if (navigator.connection != undefined) {
    console.log("Connection type: " + navigator.connection.type);       
} else {
    console.log('unaailable navigator connection type');
}
```

but, console debug message always print "Connection type: 0"
maybe connection type 0 is unknown.. i did't use phone gap. and phone gap api show me how to get network connection type (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html)

should i use phone gap to get network type?
or my web view don't support network api? but if see this table, my android web view support network api (http://mobilehtml5.org)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to check network in java file?

Then use this code

```
public static boolean isEnableNetwork(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().getType(); // If you want to know network type.

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null &&  cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

And check this url

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29)